# how to progressively add drawable to a canvas?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have points generated one by one, and when a new point is generated, I want to draw a line segment connecting with the previous point.  Like this:

```
var x by remember { mutableStateOf( 0.0f)}
var y by remember { mutableStateOf( 0.5f)}
var pStart by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset(0f, 0.5f))}

Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    canvasWidth = size.width
    canvasHeight = size.height
    val pEnd = Offset(x * canvasWidth, (1-y) * canvasHeight)
    val col = if (pEnd.y < pStart.y) Color.Green else Color.Red
    drawLine(
        start = pStart,
        end = pEnd,
        strokeWidth = 4f,
        color = col
    )
    pStart = pEnd
}
```

But this only draws the segment in a flash and no segments stay on the screen.

I know I can save the points to a list and redraw all the segments whenever a new point is added.  But I just hope to economize.  Is it possible?

Comment: No, there is no other way but to store all the points.

Comment: I don't think this is a heavy operation. You should go with the option using a list.

Comment: @PylypDukhov Sir, I wouldn't say there's NO other way.

Answer (score 0):

There's no practical other way. You COULD in fact, keep track of just two points, adding a whole new `Canvas` (all Transparent and Filling the maximum Size, stacked on top of one another), for each extra point that is added. This does seem a bit impractical, but maybe try it out and do some benchmarking to see which one checks out. This is the only OTHER way I could think of, where you do not have to store all the points and recompose every time a point is added, since all the other lines would technically be frozen in space.

In response to the somewhat (unreasonably) aggressive comment below, here's some sample code. I assume you have a stream of new points coming in so a `LiveData` object is assumed to be the source of that, which I shall be converting to a `MutableState<T>` for my use-case.

```
var latestPoint by liveData.collectAsState()
var recordedPoint by remember { mutableStateOf(latestPoint) }

var triggerDraw by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

var canvasList = mutableStateListOf<@Composable () -> Unit>Canvas>() // Canvas is the Composable

if(triggerDraw){
  canvasList.add(
    Canvas(){ 
      /* you have the recordedPoint, and  latestPoint, simply draw a line here */
    }
  )
  triggerDraw = false
}

LaunchedEffect(latestPoint){
 triggerDraw = true
}

canvasList.forEach {
  it() // Invoke the Composable here
}
```

Thanks Dad!

Comment: why don't you at least give an example of the code? Such text can be a comment, not an answer, because it doesn't answer the question, but it gives an idea of where to look.

Comment: Here you go 'Pylyp'.

Comment: `Canvas`, like any Composable, returns `Unit`, not `Canvas`. I didn't mean to offend you with my comment, just trying to help you make your answer relevant: if I don't understand your idea, most other people won't understand it either. I got the idea now, but, again, most of people won't be able to modify your code to be runnable to test it. Even if you will be able to run your code, it won't solve the authors problem, because he's looking for a way to not redraw all the lines on each recomposition, and that's what your code does anyway - all the canvases are gonna be redrawn on each recomposi

Comment: Unless I change the type of the list to `@Composable () -> Unit`.

Comment: "I know I can save the points to a list and redraw all the segments whenever a new point is added. But I just hope to economize." as I said, your solution is still not economizing, as all the canvases are gonna be redrawn on each recomposition

Comment: "I wouldn't say there's NO other way" -- as i said, this is just another way, where you don't have to store the points in a list so a single canvas recomposes all of them whenever a new point is added. Read the first line of my solution, please.

Comment: So you created this answer just to prove me wrong? But literally you wrap each point in composable, so you're still keeping all the points, just in a wrapper. Either way it doesn't answer the author's question.

Comment: "So you created this answer just to prove me wrong" - yes, but not in the sense that you seem to be applying. You said that storing the points in a list was the only way to achieve the output the user desired. I just took it as a challenge and tried to see if I could come up with anything else to do the same, which did not involve storing the points in a list. Coders code, that's just what we do. Also, I did think that every Canvas would not recompose, but it seems like it certainly would. However, they say that Compose is smart enough to only re-draw the changes, so maybe that works?

Comment: That's why I recommended benchmarking, since the internals of Compose are not something the high-level developer is generally familiar with.